# Site bar missing on Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

It seems a new design has been rolled out to Meta Stack Exchange. However, the only way I can see I'm on Meta is the browser's address bar and the placeholder in the search bar ...

[image]

I'd expect that without the Meta logo, the large number of off-topic questions we get here daily will only increase further ... so I consider this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). Also, the logo is the only one-click option to navigate to the home page if you have the left navigation collapsed.

Comment: We're investigating.

Comment: Well that wasn't intentional...rolling back the build in < 2 minutes and we'll fix the glitch. Sorry about that.

Comment: @NickCraver was this missed because your dev site (dev.so) uses the same bannerless design as Stack Overflow?

Comment: [tag:status-completed]

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard no, there are more factors than that - and we have multiple dev sites :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has been fixed in another deploy after a brief rollback there. In total, we were eliminating the mobile views from the authentication flows. This was part of an overall effort to eliminate all mobile views as we make everything responsive instead.

There's a lot of work to do here, making mobile better than it is today and at the same or better levels of performance. There are other changes we're testing with the login chrome here (think: login is global) that unfortunately bled over here on meta. I tidied this up and we're back to good here.

With mobile out of the way and part of the every day flow instead of an afterthought, we'll be able to simplify a ton of things, de-dupe a lot of things, and do oh so many future changes faster. Fun times are ahead.